# How to arrange scrollable layout for list of widgets in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to build a scrollable widget that consists of some Text widgets (and maybe some other widgets) that are produced by a function. However, I'm getting the following error:

A RenderFlex overflowed by 701 pixels on the bottom.

I'm not sure what the best layout is here. Should the scrollable Column be placed outside the container? Is a Column at the innermost nesting required? Is another Expanded widget required?

Also, the Text inside the widget list should be aligned left, not centereed.
If someone could help with a useful solution, I'd be very thankful!

Here's my current code:

```
List<Widget> getWidgetList(){
// do some stuff and return a list
return [Text("foo"), Text("bar")];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(... body:
      Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child:
          SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child:
              SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child:
                  Column(
                      children: getWidgetList()
                  )
              )
          )
      )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the overflow happens from `getWidgetList`. Remove the fixed height from `SizedBox`,

You can use `ListView`, it provide padding params,

```dart
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  children: [
    ...getWidgetList(),
  ],
),
```

**Old**

```dart
   Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child:
          SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child:
              SizedBox(
                 // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child:
                  Column(
                      children: getWidgetList()
                  )
              )
          )
      )
    );
```

Comment: so the `SizedBox` is to be removed too and in this case the whole code could be reduced to single `ListView(children: getWidgetList())`

Comment: too lazy , btw @pskink if I use `Padding` widget here(replacing container), even though It can't be const on this structure, will I get any better performance?

Comment: you will get 0.01 ms maybe, yes `Padding` is better but you will not notice that

Comment: The listView also use Slivers,  do we still get better performance on CustomScrollView?

Comment: all of them use slivers: [CustomScrollView code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/52b3dc25f6471c27b2144594abb11c741cb88f57/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart#L618)

Comment: (off Topic): What is your Linux  distro(version), the one having 4Gb of ram(If am remember correctly). I'm facing some issue with my old laptop.

Comment: Mint LDME 4 Debbie - yes 4GB but I am using vscode since the newest android studio becomes too slow now

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will do an update on this question

Comment: @pskink your one-line solution solves the problem ;) However the EdgeInsets are not kept and wrapping it by the container above destroys it, because the ListView requires to be wrapped by a Flex widget.

Comment: @BugsBuggy ListVIew `padding` parameter can be used.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh maybe fleet could be better? https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/download/, more: https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/

Comment: Padding does not work, I didn't expect that: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a RepaintBoundary widget.

Comment: I hope it is coming from your custom widget that are inside `getWidgetList`, & use `body:ListView`

Comment: right, some of them are ```const Expanded(child: Divider())```. I just removed the ```Expanded``` wrapper

Comment: also `children:[...getWidgetList(),],` is not needed `children: getWidgetList(),` is enough as `getWidgetList()` returns a `List`

Comment: Yeah, that's obvious :-D Thanks, you seem to resolve all of my problems